# Spring @Configurable annotation with AspectJ

Tags: spring, maven, spring-aop, spring-transactions, compile-time-weaving

Can't make my project compile with `Aspectj`. There's an issue with `Apache CXF` that `ResourceContext.getResource(SomeClass.class)` creates a simple object not a Spring-managed one. So I would like to use weaving and `@Configurable` to come over this hardship. I got it to work in my test Spring Boot application (I could provide a link on the Github if needed) with the following set up using `@Configurable` itself and `@EnableSpringConfigured`:

Here is a snapshot of my pom.xml (Spring version is 4.3.3.RELEASE):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and the `aspectj-maven-plugin` plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, when I try to apply the configuration above in the real project in my company I get this weird error:

```
[ERROR] *path to the java file being weaving* can't determine annotations of missing type javax.transaction.Transactional
[ERROR] when weaving type *the full java class name*
[ERROR] when weaving classes
[ERROR] when weaving
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=27 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error at (no source information available)
```

My test project doesn't use `@Transactional` but the real one does. So I've tried to add `spring-tx` and `persistence-api` dependencies but nothing works. And the last note: the project is built successful the second time I run `mvn install` and unsuccessful every time I run `mvn clean install`.

Any help is much appreciated as I'm really stuck with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following dependency to the classpath should solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, Stas! It really solved the current problem. Now I can build the project but, unfortunetely, I've found some of Configurable classes makes using of Transactional as well. It causes the following error in runtime: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post-processor tried to replace bean instance of type *The original class name*  with (proxy) object of type *Some weird weaved proxy class name* - not supported for aspect-configured classes!`

Comment: @snoopy-whoopy This is a different problem, so open a new question for it. If you found and answer, post your answer as well!

Comment: @cb4 Thanks for advice! I found the answer but I am newbie here so should I answer e.g. as a regular answer or as a comment to my problem description?

Comment: @snoopy-whoopy You should create a brand new question, then post your answer. It's cleaner that way and will allow others to search for that specific problem. Cheers!